# Spring context loading and component scan

Tags: java, spring

This seems like a basic query but want to know if component scan tag can load applicationcontext files in the jar file?

For example:

I have defined component scan for package : com.x.y.z which is inside a jar file and this jar file has applicationContext.xml defined for the jar file inside com.x.y.x.spring package. Will this context file get loaded while scanning for the components?

Also , this applicationcontext has reference to another xml file inside the same jar. Will dat also be loaded along with the applicationContext file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing a component-scan in `com.x.y.z`, try importing the `applicationContext.xml` of that jar by placing this in your own spring context:

```
<import  resource="classpath:com/x/y/x/spring/applicationContext.xml"/>
```

I presume, this context file will define the beans of the `com.x.y.z` package. Spring will recursively load all context files referenced by this imported file as well.

Comment: ok but I have not defined beans using xml format , all the beans are defined using annotations so if I place a componentScan tag inside applicationContext.xml will dat scan the packages also for components?

Comment: If you have `<context:component-scan base-package="com.x.y.z"/>` inside `com/x/y/x/spring/applicationContext.xml` and you import that xml in your own context xml, then you'll have all the `@Component` (and similarly) annotated beans from the `com.x.y.z` package in your context.

Answer (score 0):

Component scan only look for class files having the Spring annotation.

If you want to load Spring config files then you have to specify their path in your mail spring context configuration.